# C Function Call Loop

Tags: c, loops

Lets say i've got functions named Function1,Function2,Function3 etc.
Is there a way of calling one of the functions in a loop each time?

```
for(i=1;i<Max;i++)
{
Function^();
}
```

Comment: Are the number of functions and their names known at compile time?

Comment: Yes....all the function names are known

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void func1(void)
{
    printf( "func1\n" );
}

void func2(void)
{
    printf( "func2\n" );
}

void func3(void)
{
    printf( "func3\n" );
}

typedef void ( *func )(void);

int main(void)
{
    func m_func[3] = {func1, func2, func3};
    int index;

    for( index = 0; index < 3; index++ )
    {
        m_func[index]();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @PaulR: C11 draft standard `Section 5.1.2.2.3 Program termination [...] reaching the } that terminates the main function returns a value of 0. [...]`

Comment: That does what i want ...but i was hoping there is a way of avoiding to at some point list all the functions....func1,func2,func3...

Comment: @RangoTango: What do you mean? You want to avoid what?

Comment: ive got about 30 functions named func1 to func30. Using method above, i'll have to list down all my 30 functions in the array even though the only difference in the fuction name is a number. I was wondering if i could get away with something like func##n## in a loop controlled by n

Comment: @RangoTango: I am afraid it cannot be done. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16216585/token-pasting-in-c-using-a-variable-that-increments

Comment: @EOF: given that at least one well known C compiler still hasn't achieved full adoption of C99 it's probably a little premature to start assuming that everyone is using C11.

Comment: @PaulR: Well, the same *does* apply to C99, and a C99-compiler *is* a requirement for POSIX now, so really it's just Microsoft that's sitting with its thumb up somewhere.

Comment: @EOF: well Microsoft-slackness aside, in the interest of portability it doesn't hurt to `return 0;` at the end of `main`, and `void main` is always an abomination. And don't forget embedded compilers too. which tend to lag about 10 years or more behind the curve.

Comment: @PaulR: Oh, I'm certainly not advocating *against* treating `int main()` like any other function, including explicitly `return`ing a proper value. That's what I do, myself.

Answer (score 2):

Not in a loop, but with the predefined `__COUNTER__` the following can be done.

Construct a macro defining the declaration and the function call with a counter parameter (`CALLFUNC0`), so counter can be used twice without incrementing it.

Then build a chain of macros calling the previous macro twice (`CALLFUNC2`, `CALLFUNC4`, ...) For 30 functions until `CALLFUNC16` is needed (16+8+4+2=30).

Then define a function using the `CALLFUNC30` macro. The `CALLFUNC30` macro can be used only once because `__COUNTER__` is incremented every time it is used.

In my example the functions names are `void myfuncx1(int, int)` to `void myfuncx30(int, int)`

```
/* callmyfunctions.h */

#define PASTE0(x,y) x ## y
#define PASTE1(x,y) PASTE0(x,y)

extern void callmyfuncs(int arg1, int arg2);
```

```
/* callmyfunctions.c */

#include "callmyfunctions.h"

_Static_assert(__COUNTER__ == 0, "__COUNTER__ must not be used before");
#define CALLFUNC0(func, counter, ...) extern void PASTE1(func,counter)(int arg1, int arg2);\
                                      PASTE1(func,counter)(__VA_ARGS__);
#define CALLFUNC1(func, ...) CALLFUNC0(func, __COUNTER__, __VA_ARGS__)
#define CALLFUNC2(func, ...) CALLFUNC1(func, __VA_ARGS__) CALLFUNC1(func, __VA_ARGS__)
#define CALLFUNC4(func, ...) CALLFUNC2(func, __VA_ARGS__) CALLFUNC2(func, __VA_ARGS__)
#define CALLFUNC8(func, ...) CALLFUNC4(func, __VA_ARGS__) CALLFUNC4(func, __VA_ARGS__)
#define CALLFUNC16(func, ...) CALLFUNC8(func, __VA_ARGS__) CALLFUNC8(func, __VA_ARGS__)

#define CALLFUNC30(func, ...) CALLFUNC16(func, __VA_ARGS__) CALLFUNC8(func, __VA_ARGS__) \
                              CALLFUNC4(func, __VA_ARGS__) CALLFUNC2(func, __VA_ARGS__)

void callmyfuncs(int arg1, int arg2)
{
    CALLFUNC30(myfuncx, arg1, arg2)
}
```

```
    /* callmyfunctions_test.c */

    #include <stdio.h>

    #include "callmyfunctions.h"

    _Static_assert(__COUNTER__ == 0, "__COUNTER__ must not be used before");
    #define DEFINEFUNC1(func) void PASTE1(func,__COUNTER__)(int arg1, int arg2) {\
            printf("%s %d %d\n", __func__, arg1, arg2); \
        }
    #define DEFINEFUNC2(func) DEFINEFUNC1(func) DEFINEFUNC1(func)
    #define DEFINEFUNC4(func) DEFINEFUNC2(func) DEFINEFUNC2(func)
    #define DEFINEFUNC8(func) DEFINEFUNC4(func) DEFINEFUNC4(func)
    #define DEFINEFUNC16(func) DEFINEFUNC8(func) DEFINEFUNC8(func)
    #define DEFINEFUNC30(func) DEFINEFUNC16(func) DEFINEFUNC8(func) \
                               DEFINEFUNC4(func) DEFINEFUNC2(func)

    DEFINEFUNC30(myfuncx)

    int main(void) {
        callmyfuncs(0,1);
        callmyfuncs(2,3);
        return 0;
    }
```

```
$ gcc callmyfunctions.c callmyfunctions_test.c -Wall -Wextra
```

```
$ ./a.out
myfuncx1 0 1
myfuncx2 0 1
myfuncx3 0 1
myfuncx4 0 1
myfuncx5 0 1
myfuncx6 0 1
myfuncx7 0 1
myfuncx8 0 1
myfuncx9 0 1
myfuncx10 0 1
myfuncx11 0 1
myfuncx12 0 1
myfuncx13 0 1
myfuncx14 0 1
myfuncx15 0 1
myfuncx16 0 1
myfuncx17 0 1
myfuncx18 0 1
myfuncx19 0 1
myfuncx20 0 1
myfuncx21 0 1
myfuncx22 0 1
myfuncx23 0 1
myfuncx24 0 1
myfuncx25 0 1
myfuncx26 0 1
myfuncx27 0 1
myfuncx28 0 1
myfuncx29 0 1
myfuncx30 0 1
myfuncx1 2 3
myfuncx2 2 3
myfuncx3 2 3
myfuncx4 2 3
myfuncx5 2 3
myfuncx6 2 3
myfuncx7 2 3
myfuncx8 2 3
myfuncx9 2 3
myfuncx10 2 3
myfuncx11 2 3
myfuncx12 2 3
myfuncx13 2 3
myfuncx14 2 3
myfuncx15 2 3
myfuncx16 2 3
myfuncx17 2 3
myfuncx18 2 3
myfuncx19 2 3
myfuncx20 2 3
myfuncx21 2 3
myfuncx22 2 3
myfuncx23 2 3
myfuncx24 2 3
myfuncx25 2 3
myfuncx26 2 3
myfuncx27 2 3
myfuncx28 2 3
myfuncx29 2 3
myfuncx30 2 3
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #define MAX 5
 void function1();
 void function2();
 void function3();
 int main()
 {
    int i;
    for(i=1;i<MAX;i++)
    {
        switch(i)
        {
           case 1: function1(); break;
           case 2: function2(); break;
           case 3: function3(); break;
        }  
    }
    return 0;
 }
 void function1()
 {
   printf("In One");
 }
 void function2()
 {
   printf("In Two");
 }
 void function3()
 {
   printf("In Three");
 }
```